# How to correctly setup a local ReasonMl / Bucklescript dependencies

Tags: npm, reason, bucklescript

New to ReasonML, and I probably don't understand the bucklescript documentation for setting up 
a module as a dependency.

1. ReasonML project, compiles correctly, with the file MyUtils.re in directory ~/ml/myutils/src.
2. second ReasonML project in ~/ml/project2/src, file Demo.re starts with

   open MyUtils;

I installed the first project: I tried both

```
npm install -g
```

inside ~/ml/myutils, and 
    npm install ../myutils --save 
inside  ~/ml/project2

the module looks installed globally :

```
 npm list -g | grep myutils
```

├─┬ myutils@0.1.3 -> /home/user/ml/myutils

and also locally

```
 npm list | grep myutils
```

└─┬ myutils@0.1.3 -> /home/user/ml/myutils

bsconfig.json

```
"bs-dependencies": [
"@glennsl/bs-json",
"myutils"
```

],

package.json

```
 "dependencies": {
"@glennsl/bs-json": "^5.0.2",
"myutils": "file:../myutils"
```

}

but `npm run build` :

```
We've found a bug for you!
  /home/user/ml/project2/src/Demo.re 2:6-12

  1 │
  2 │ open MyUtils;
  3 │
  4 │

  The module or file MyUtils can't be found.
  - If it's a third-party dependency:
    - Did you list it in bsconfig.json?
    - Did you run `bsb` instead of `bsb -make-world`
      (latter builds third-parties)?
  - Did you include the file's directory in bsconfig.json?
```

I tried adding `file:../myutils` to bsconfig.json: no change

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@gash go check `bsconfig.json` of `myutils`. 
Set `"namespace": false`

If Myutils namespace is `true`. it will probably create extra module layer for you.

Something like `MyUtils.MyUtils`